# How much should be put in your PowerShell profile?

Tags: powershell

Just starting to get interested in PowerShell and adding some customizations into my profile.

My question is how much is too much when it comes to a profile? There's a number of modules that I want to load for each session. Is performance affected at all during a session if I load too many modules in the profile or is that purely a startup concern?

Answer (score 2):

I usually set alias like vim and other settings of the shell in profile. In terms of your question, you need to load modules for each session, load all of them in profile is okay. modules loaded will be always within the memory, so it will affect performance of your computer. In Powershell 3.0, you don't need to load modules manually anymore, they will be load automatically in case of needed. you just need to set your  PSModulePath environment variable properly to make sure your modules could be find if you put your module in locations other than default.